# Equation to find the collaboration between neighbors in SOM in unsupervised learning

Tags: machine-learning

In Kohonen's SOM algorithm, the equation to find the collaboration is:

$$
\mathit{Damp}(i,j) = \exp\left(-\frac{\mathit{LDist}(i,j)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$

I know that LDist is the lattice distance and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. I am just wondering why they are squared? Can anyone help me to visualize the equation or explain to me what is going on in the above equation?

Comment: Are you familiar with the normal distribution?

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with normal distribution and I know that the above equation is related to that. I just want a clear explanation why the two terms (sigma and distance) are squared in the equation as I could not find one that explains this phenomenon clearly.

Comment: The distance function is to some extent an arbitrary choice; there are others you could use. The one you describe is known as *Gaussian kernel*, and is popular in machine learning.